# Unable to access Microphone in Chrome browser but working in other browsers when application is deployed on AKS. .NET Framework 4.5 is used

Tags: google-chrome, azure-aks, microphone

I have an application built on .NET Framework 4.5 and is deployed on AKS. I have a feature to access the Microphone which is working on Firefox/Edge and Safari but Chrome is not allowing the application to access the Microphone. It is showing the below error.

[ErrorScreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEs1L.png)

I have tried to access media in chrome using

```
navigator.mediaDevices
    .getUserMedia({ video: false, audio: true })
    .then((stream) => { window.localStream = stream; window.localAudio.srcObject = stream; window.localAudio.autoplay = true;
    })
```